# HtmlAgilityPack returns only first match

Tags: xml, vb.net, youtube, html-agility-pack

```
<entry xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom" xmlns:media="http://search.yahoo.com/mrss/" xmlns:gd="http://schemas.google.com/g/2005" xmlns:yt="http://gdata.youtube.com/schemas/2007">
    <id>http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/users/upvZG-5ko_eiXAupbDfxWw</id>
    <published>2005-10-02T16:06:36.000Z</published>
    <updated>2014-05-29T20:18:58.000Z</updated>
    <category scheme="http://schemas.google.com/g/2005#kind" term="http://gdata.youtube.com/schemas/2007#userProfile"/>
    <category scheme="http://gdata.youtube.com/schemas/2007/channeltypes.cat" term="DIRECTOR"/>
    <title type="text">CNN</title>
    <content type="text">CNN operates as a division of Turner Broadcasting System, which is a subsidiary of Time Warner. CNN identifies itself as -- and is widely known to be - the most trusted source for news and information. The CNN umbrella includes nine cable and satellite television networks, two radio networks, the CNN Digital Network, which is the top network of news Web sites in the United States, and CNN Newsource, the world's most extensively syndicated news service. CNN is proud of our ability to bring you up-to-the-minute news from around the world, as a result of our many extensions.</content>
    <link rel="alternate" type="text/html" href="http://www.youtube.com/channel/UCupvZG-5ko_eiXAupbDfxWw"/>
    <link rel="self" type="application/atom+xml" href="http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/users/upvZG-5ko_eiXAupbDfxWw"/>
    <author>
        <name>CNN</name>
        <uri>http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/users/CNN</uri>
    </author>
    <gd:feedLink rel="http://gdata.youtube.com/schemas/2007#user.subscriptions" href="http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/users/cnn/subscriptions" countHint="6"/>
    <gd:feedLink rel="http://gdata.youtube.com/schemas/2007#user.contacts" href="http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/users/cnn/contacts" countHint="4250"/>
    <gd:feedLink rel="http://gdata.youtube.com/schemas/2007#user.inbox" href="http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/users/cnn/inbox"/>
    <gd:feedLink rel="http://gdata.youtube.com/schemas/2007#user.playlists" href="http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/users/cnn/playlists"/>
    <gd:feedLink rel="http://gdata.youtube.com/schemas/2007#user.uploads" href="http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/users/cnn/uploads" countHint="58269"/>
    <gd:feedLink rel="http://gdata.youtube.com/schemas/2007#user.newsubscriptionvideos" href="http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/users/cnn/newsubscriptionvideos"/>
    <yt:location>US</yt:location>
    <yt:statistics lastWebAccess="1970-01-01T00:00:00.000Z" subscriberCount="484272" videoWatchCount="0" viewCount="0" totalUploadViews="400764857"/>
    <media:thumbnail url="http://i1.ytimg.com/i/upvZG-5ko_eiXAupbDfxWw/1.jpg?v=51df0b06"/>
    <yt:username>cnn</yt:username>
</entry>
```

I tried this code but it only return the first match, I need the value of countHint to be equal to **58269** in

```
<gd:feedLink rel="http://gdata.youtube.com/schemas/2007#user.uploads" href="http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/users/cnn/uploads" countHint="58269"/>
```

My code:

```
Dim request As HttpWebRequest = WebRequest.Create("http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/users/cnn")
Dim response As HttpWebResponse = request.GetResponse()
Dim reader As StreamReader = New StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream())
Dim page As String = reader.ReadToEnd()
Dim dokuman = New HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument()
dokuman.LoadHtml(page)
Dim gets As HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlNodeCollection = dokuman.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//entry")
For Each node In gets
    If node.ChildNodes("gd:feedLink").Attributes("href").Value = "http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/users/cnn/uploads" Then
        '......
    End If
Next
```

How can I get a value of **58269** with HtmlAgiltyPack? If i try

```
dokuman.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//gd:feedLink")
```

then an error is thrown!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that [HtmlAgilityPack doesn't support XPath containing prefix](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/discussions/211321). You can workaround this limitation by selecting all children of `<entry>` element, then use LINQ to narrow down the result by node name :

```
Dim result As HtmlNode = _
        dokuman.DocumentNode _
           .SelectNodes("//entry/*") _
           .FirstOrDefault(Function(x) _
                               x.Name = "gd:feedlink" AndAlso _
                               x.Attributes("href").Value = "http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/users/cnn/uploads")
If Not result Is Nothing Then
    'this is a better practice for accessing attribute value from HtmlNode...'
    '...to avoid exception if such attribute not found'
    Console.WriteLine(result.GetAttributeValue("countHint", "not found"))
End If
```